# Need to use only while or for loop to create mesh of points in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested

Please, help me how to use nested while loop.

Simply, after creating 1 row of point with the same Y,(in X direction) :

```
while minX < maxX:
    minX += 2000.0
    X.append(minX)
    Y.append(minY)
```

need to create a new row of point with Y increased by 2000.0 m.
And do this till Y < maxY

I have: X min, Y min and X max, Y max. Need to create mesh of point with increasing distance 2000.0 m (starting from minX, maxY) between point in this boundaries.

```
# Get a mesh points for each polygon:

import arcpy # csv
from arcpy import env

print "Creating and defining variables."
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\anna_pavlenko\Desktop\data"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

theme = 'interestAreas.shp' 
# Look for .next()  in SearchCursor, need a loop
# the same when we read line by line
for i in theme:
    Curs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme, 'SHAPE@').next()
    polygon = Curs[0]
    ext = polygon.extent
del Curs

# Find min X, Y and max X, Y for each polygon and write it to the file:
print 'xmin is: ', ext.XMin
print 'ymin is: ', ext.YMin
print 'xmax is: ', ext.XMax
print 'ymax is: ', ext.YMax
minX = ext.XMin
minY = ext.YMin

maxX = ext.XMax
maxY = ext.YMax
print "**********************"
print "Given x and y coordinates of min and max points:"
print "Get new X coordinates of distance 2000 meters:"       

while minY < maxY:
    minY += 2000.0
        while minX < maxX:
            minX += 2000.0
            X.append(minX)
            Y.append(minY)
     X.append(minX)
     Y.append(minY)
```

gave me: 1 row by X (from min to max) and 1 colon of point by Y (from minY to maxY) from Xmax - last X.
But needed rows of point like this:

[image: input - polygons]

[image: output points]

Please, help me to create rows of points/ mesh grid.

I got some answer from this web site by using numpy,
But really need to use only nested while loop for this.

Also I need to move to next polygon in the file  to get points in distance 3500.0 m and to third polygon - to 4500 m.

Comment: can you show some input and expected output?

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to paste pictures here?

Comment: I attached images: input - polygons

output  points in boundaries min, max X, Y

Comment: Why do you "need" to use while loops? `numpy.mgrid` or `numpy.meshgrid` are the obvious solutions. If it's a given task to solve the problem by writing a function yourself, I think us doing that for you is counterproductive.